# How to add usage hints for our custom methods and properties in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: Code completion with usage hints at the bottom]

In the attached image Xcode is showing usage hints (two lines at the bottom) for its classes. Similarly, is that possible to have my own hints for my custom class methods and properties?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do this by adding a specifically formatted comments above the declaration in your header. e.x:

```
/**
 *  This is my awesome new property!!!
 */
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *someProperty;


/**
 *  An even cooler description!
 *
 *  @param  string  some string
 *  @param  arr some array
 */
- (void)myAwesomeMethodWithAweomseParamOfType:(NSString *)string andOtherParam:(NSArray *)arr;
```

Then when I head over to my implementation file and start typing...

[image]
[image]

However, if you don't want to bother remembering all the specifics of how to format these comments, download [VVDocumneter](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) from github. It's a Xcode plugin that will automatically add these comments. All you have to do is navigate to the line above the declaration, and hit `///`.

Comment: +1 for the great answer, for downvote i think you are paying back for somebode ;)

Comment: It appears it is not supported in Xcode 4.5.1 and earlier versions. Works well with the latest Xcode version. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know why there are only so few up-votes. It is from 2013, but still very useful